# Performant language/method to find a series of integers within an expansion of pi

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, pi

I am writing an interactive educational app that locates a series of integers, input by a user, in a million-digit expansion of pi. I am trying to decide upon an approach. Which programming language/method would be fastest?

Comment: Fastest for you to write or fastest to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just ordinary old substring search.

1. Store the precomputed digits in a string.
2. Use one of the linear-time substring search algorithms, like [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), to search for the user-entered substring.  Actually, the naive O(n^2) substring search (which is how C's `strstr()` is typically implemented) is probably fast enough if the user-entered string will be less than 100 digits or so, and will almost certainly be faster than any fancier algorithm for user-entered strings of less than 10 digits or so.  (These numbers are educated guesses.)

These algorithms *can* be expressed in any language, but if you use an interpreted language like Python, try using whatever built-in string-searching function(s) (including [regexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)) it has before implementing KMP yourself -- built-in functions will be internally implemented in a compiled language, so should be a constant factor faster.

Comment: How could one tell that this would be faster than something like BBP?

Comment: What I'm suggesting isn't a competitor to the BBP algorithm.  You need to first (step 1) compute all the digits you need somehow (e.g. using BBP), and then (step 2) do substring search.  You only ever need to do step 1 once.

Comment: BPP will calculate just the nth digit. I was trying to wrap my head around whether that would help or not.